# Android Calculation error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a Cab Application for a class I am in and in the MainActivity.java I have added this.  The problem I am having is when I get to the line "final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);"  This is a intro to Android app development class and why Java was not a requirement is beyond me, but it is what it is and I'm feeling more confident in what I'm doing, but I can't seem to figure out why this line isn't working.  I do have a string setup in the strings.xml file for txtResult.  If anyone can provide insight on what I might have missed it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
//Declarations
double costPerMile=3.25;
int numberOfMiles;
double baseCost = 3.00;
double totalCost;
String carChoice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText miles=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdistance);
    final Spinner group=(Spinner)findViewById(R.array.Cab_Type);
    Button cost= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    cost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Todo
            numberOfMiles = Integer.parseInt(miles.getText().toString());
            totalCost = (costPerMile * numberOfMiles) + baseCost;

            DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
            carChoice = group.getSelectedItem().toString();

            result.setText("You chose the " + carChoice + " which will cost you " + currency.format(totalCost));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Explain the problem in more detail. "Isn't working" is not enough. If it crashes, check out the logcat. You might want to learn how to read a stacktrace (it's very simple though, so don't worry)

Comment: When trying to run the application i receive the error.
Error:(33, 58) error: cannot find symbol variable txtResult
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: "The" error? What error? Nvm you edited. Edit the question instead though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do have a string setup in the strings.xml file for txtResult

What you're trying to do won't work unless you have a TextView in your activity_main.xml with the id of txtResult.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResult" />
```

If you're trying to make the TextView display the string that you have set to txtResult in strings.xml you could do this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:text="@string/txtResult" />
```

Comment: So if I want this to display on a separate activity should I set that up on that activities xml?

Comment: Yes, when your new activity starts you'll make a similar call to `setContentView(R.layout.my_new_layout)`, and whatever you'd like to be displayed by that activity should live in `my_new_layout.xml`.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed me.  As soon as I added the strings properly to the new Activity all the errors cleared right up.  Now it is just the way that it's calling the next activity, but I'll try to search that one out.  Thanks again for the help.